# How to mark certain parts of string to be read as code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on ASP.NET Web Forms application. A lot of my information is stored in XML files on the server side. Via Ajax calls I retrieve some of that data for use in the front end.

The problem is that sometimes I have to write in the XML file some string, part of which should be recognized as JS code. What I mean is for example this:

```
<Render>
  <![CDATA[<center><input type='checkbox' value=" + row[2] + " /></center>]]>
</Render>
```

Here I get this piece of data from a place in JavaScript where I have array `row` and I have index `[2]` but instead showing me the value of the element with this index the debugger shows me that the checkbox value is literally `row[2]` (not recognized as array).

The way I handle this in JavaScript is:

```
 options.mRender = function (data, type, row) { return options.Render; };
```

where `options.Render` is the actual string `<center><input type='checkbox' value=" + row[2] + " />`.

I made a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7S3tA/1/) example. The idea is when I write `person[0]` to get `Ivan` instead of `person[0]` which is the result now.

I know that if I add `eval()` like this -  `$('#appnd').append(eval(txt));` but I can't figure out how to get use of this in my code since I'm passing the whole markup and not only the variable.

Comment: Can't you split up the returned XML string? That way, you can handle the JS code separately, and eventually still transmit all code. (I'm not an expert in this, just giving some abstract ideas)

Comment: @Dreamonic If there's no more straigh forward way I maybe edn up parsing the result almost as you suggested but I think, there must be some standard way to handle this scenario since it seems very common.

Comment: I have no idea, this is not really my field of expertise. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function parse(text) {
    return text.replace(/[a-z]+\[\d+\]/g,function(exp){return eval(exp);});
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7S3tA/6/)

It simply takes the input and replaces parts of it that look like `array[index]` with whatever `eval` does with it.

This solution does **not** seem like a good idea to me and I agree that there should be some standard way of doing it (better), but I just can't think of another way of doing it.

Edit: It would probably be more reliable if you could mark the JS code in the XML somehow before it is sent to the client like `<center><input type='checkbox' value=" + BEGINJS>row[2]<ENDJS + " />` then your regex wouldn't have to guess wildly at what the JS code will look like.

Comment: Seems fine, I think I may end up using something like this but I get a strange error when try to use it in my own code - `Uncaught ReferenceError: ow is not defined` - `VM..` have you ever see this? Sorry, my bad, just typo in my code. It's working fine. I'll wait a bit more and accept this if nothing better shows up

Comment: My first guess would be that your expression is not matched properly by the regex. It only captures lower case letters and perhaps there was a capital letter somewhere in your code? See my edit for another idea to prevent this.